# MySQL STR_TO_DATE insert null

Tags: mysql

I need to insert datetime to mysql table, using STR_TO_DATE, but below command givnig datetime column always NULL.

```
insert  into DETECTED values(NULL,STR_TO_DATE('2017-01-21 12:36:32','%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

What's the problem with above command.

Comment: NULL insteadof NUUL.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STR_DATE has only 2 args and you specify the wrong delimiter.

**use:**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2017-01-21 12:36:32','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

result : 2017-01-21 12:36:32

**like this**

```
insert  into DETECTED 
  values(STR_TO_DATE('2017-01-21 12:36:32','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
```